# Count commas in a csv file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm trying to count the commas row by row in a `.csv` file. Unfortunately it always comes up to zero.

```
    import csv 

    with open('Test.csv') as csv_file:
       csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
       for row in csv_reader:
           numCommas = row.read().count(',')
           print numCommas
```

But I am always getting 0.

Comment: Just all commas in the file/row, or all delimiting commas? (Some could be quoted.)

Comment: your script will give error, as your variable row will be of type list and list object don't have attribut read().  If you want to count commas then don't read file with csv.reader. You can directly iterate over csv_file object.

Comment: Thanks for reply I used this method len(row)

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to count the commas and don't need the data, the `csv` module is not required:

```
with open('Test.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    for line in csv_file:
        print(line.count(','))
```

Answer (score 2):

On python2 you can try in this way, but you will have to change the delimiter:

```
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='\t')

numCommas = row[0].count(',')
```

If you have the delimiter as `,` this is how the `row` looks like:

```
['a', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

With `\t` as delimiter, the row is in this way:

```
['a,d,f,g,h']
```

So in this way you can have the number of commas for each row and not the total count

Answer (score 2):

Just read the file and count `','`

```
with open('Test.csv') as csv_file:
    count = csv_file.read().count(',')
```

Comment: This counts all the commas in the file, not the commas per line.

Comment: I tried this one is not working I used this method len(row)

Answer (score 1):

From your example above the `row` in `csv_reader` is a list. It's not a string separated by comma. When you read the file through `csv.reader()` you breaking the rows down to each columns and storing them into a list and then it's put inside csv reader object.

For your purposes, may be you can simply use `len(row)` if you want the count of columns or items in the row.

Answer (score 1):

Code you have shared will give error, because in your for loop **row** will be list. And list object don't have attribute 'read'.

And you have used **csv.reader**, so it will give you each row in form of a list. So when you are iterating csv_reader object in for loop row variable will be of type list.

**If you want to count number of columns** in each row you can simply print len(row) inside for loop.

```
print len(row)
```

**But if you want to count number of commas** only, then you need to read file without using csv.reader.

Answer (score 0):

It comes up with zero because the csv file is separated with the delimiter and the "row" variable is a list object.

You can get the count of comma(s) in str object like this:

```
a = "a,b,b,"
print(a.count(","))
```

This cannot be applied for the list, so you need to apply count for individual entries in your "row" variable to get the count of commas(if you need count for each entry in row) or you can read the file as a text file. and get the commas by readlines method.

Answer (score 0):

```
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
```

This line separates the elements by ',' and return a list. For instance, a csv row could be

```
100, 200, 300, 400
```

The list returned would be `[100, 200, 300, 400]`

To count the comma, subtract 1 from the number of elements. `i.e.` 4 elements = 3 commas

***FIXED VERSION:***

```
with open('Test.csv') as csv_file:
   csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
   for row in csv_reader:
       print (len(row)-1)
```

Comment: You are right but some description comma is there so I need to know how many comma's is there.

Comment: The one advantage of this approach is that it will correctly identify quoted commas, which may be useful for the original poster.

Comment: @smviswa Do you mean quoted commas? This approach works even with a blank row like this `,,,,,,,`